# Installing Firefox in Docker Python Image

Tags: docker, firefox

```
FROM python:3.9.4-slim-buster

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN sudo apt update && apt install firefox -y -f
RUN firefox --version || (echo "Error: Failed to install Firefox" && exit 1)
```

I was running the code build for my app and noticed that there is something wrong when the build exited and I got the error message(below) how can i fix this to get Firefox to be downloaded successfully?

> E: Package 'firefox' has no installation candidate The command
> '/bin/sh -c sudo apt update && apt install firefox -y -f' returned a
> non-zero code: 100

Comment: Thanks for your first post. It's not actually asking a question though. Can you edit it to ask a question ?

Comment: I have updated the post to ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is not in the default package list for Debian Buster so you need to add it yourself.

**Option 1: Debian Image**

Using the same base image as in the question.

```
FROM python:3.9.4-slim-buster

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y wget

RUN install -d -m 0755 /etc/apt/keyrings && \
    wget -q https://packages.mozilla.org/apt/repo-signing-key.gpg -O- | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.asc > /dev/null && \
    echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.asc] https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla.list > /dev/null && \
    echo "Package: *\nPin: origin packages.mozilla.org\nPin-Priority: 1000" | tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla 

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y firefox
```

**Option 2: Alpine Image**

Using an Alpine base image.

```
FROM python:3.9.4-alpine

RUN apk add firefox
```